# Marshalling string from C# to char[] of C++

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, char, marshalling

I am trying to marshal data from C# to C++ DLL. For which, I have following C++ code.

```
// C++ Function in DLL
int __declspec(dllexport) DataAnalyze(AllInfo *&all)
{
   return 0;
}

// Structure
typedef struct
{
    char model[100];
    char log[_MAX_PATH];
    char path[_MAX_PATH];
}AllInfo;
```

Here is my C# code.

```
public unsafe void Execute()
{
  // Assigning values
  public AllInfo ana_alls = new AllInfo();
  AllInfo adt = new AllInfo(0);
  adt.Eye_img_num = 5;
  adt.Flow_log = @"D:\\HTML\\File.txt";
  adt.Pano_path = @"D:\\HTML\\Img.bmp";
  ana_alls = adt;

  // Preparing data for marshalling
  IntPtr intPtrsAll = new IntPtr();
  intPtrsAll = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(AllInfo)));
  Marshal.StructureToPtr<AllInfo>(ana_alls, intPtrsAll, false);

  // DLL calling
  int ret = 0 - DataAnalyze(ref intPtrsAll);
}

// Structure
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct AllInfo
{
    public AllInfo(int n)
    {
        this.model = string.Empty;
        this.path = string.Empty;
        this.log = string.Empty;
    }

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 100)]
    public string model;   

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string log;   

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260)]
    public string path;  
}

// DLL Calling
[DllImport(@"D:\\HTML\\Data\\DLL\\Dara_Dll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int DataAnalyze(ref IntPtr ana_all);
```

In the C++ method, I am getting data in path of AllInfo *&all as follow:

```
path :{'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','\0','D',':','\\','H','T','M','L','\\','I','m','g','.','b','m','p','\0','\0',........}
```

I am getting similar output for log also. I don't know why '\0' added from 0 to 7 index of each char[] data in C++ that is coming from C#. Where am I doing it wrong?

Comment: string in c++ are terminate with '\0'.  So it indicates in c# that you have an empty string.

Comment: @jdweng but it is showing data after 7 index of path array in c++

Comment: From : AllInfo *&all  To : AllInfo *all   You are passing an address (IntPtr)

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I am passing an address

Comment: `StructLayout` also needs `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` because `char` in C++ is ANSI. Also you are not disposing the Ptr with `Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem`, but unclear why you would do any of this: just declare your PInvoke as `extern int DataAnalyze(ref AllIInfo ana_all);`

Comment: @Charlieface Can you please tell me in detail, it would be very helpfull.

Comment: Which bit are you struggling with? The struct needs `[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]` and the Pinvoke as I said. Then you can remove the pointer allocation andcopying, just pass `ana_alls` straight through

Comment: @Charlieface I have tried to `ana_alls` but it is showing error in c++ DLL

Comment: What error? Please also add your current code to your question. Can you also add the full C++ code of how you read the data back